# create an executable jar with source code for debug

Tags: java, maven, jar

I know how to create a JAR file with the source code with maven, and also create an executable JAR. But my question is if there is any way of creating an executable JAR (so it contains all the .class files) that also contains the source code (so for each .class its corresponding .java file).

I want this for debugging with eclipse since my maven project is a library for another project and when debugging the bigger project I loose track when the execution reaches my library because the source code is missing in the JAR. I've found a solution among this forums that suggests to create two jars, one executable and another with .java files and set the source path in the IDE to point to the code JAR, but I would like to work with a unique JAR instead of two. Is that possible? if not with maven with another java tool? For instance merging both JAR files?

Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your source directory as additinal resource directory

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This will place the java files next to the class files - I do not know if your IDE supports debugging with this structure. Usually @Brian Agnew suggested way is the way to go.

Comment: hum ok ok with `mvn package` and your solution works perfectly. Just adding the generated JAR file in the library dependencies in eclipse, I can debug through the code. This way I have an executable JAR with also the source code for debugging in just one file. I find it more clean and easy than maintaining two separated files. Anyway Lots of thanks @Brian Agnew  and @FrVaBe

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that if you're usign Maven you could create the binary as one deployable and the source jar as another. That way, your IDE should be able to transparently load the source corresponding to the binary jar you're using (in IDE it gives me a 'download' option).

See [this link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-and-deploy-a-source-jar-file-for-my-project.html) for more info.

> The maven-source-plugin can be used to generate a source code jarW
>   file for a project. Deploying this source jar to a remote repository
>   can be useful for other developers so that they can 'attach source'
>   and debug into the project source code.

Comment: yes I followed the instructions in that link. I though that was for being able to generate a single JAR file with .class and .java files. I tried to execute the     maven clean deploy but I get the following error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project hnm_java: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
` and don't know what to do.